Regex to match COBOL Style Move statement
I am trying to write two Regex statements to extract the source and target of a COBOL style Move statement of the form
Move Customer.Name New.Name

The expression (?<=Move\s*)(\w\.*)*(?<=.*) gives me the source field (Customer.Name) but I am struggling to get the target.The expression (?<=Move\s*(\w\.*)*)(\w\.*)*(?<=.*) still gives me the source name. Any thoughts on what I am doing wrong would be much appreciated.
Thanks`

I may be misunderstanding what you're trying to achieve, but a simple Move\s+(.+)\s+(.+) should match it properly, no?

You can use the following patterns:
\b(?<=Move\s+)\w+(?:\.\w+)*

See Regex #1 demo. The (?<=\bMove\s+) part matches location that is immediately preceded with a whole word Move and one or more whitespaces and \w+(?:\.\w+)* matches a word and then zero or more occurrences of a dot + a word.
To get the target, you can use
(?<=\bMove\s+\w+(?:\.\w+)*\s+)\w+(?:\.\w+)*

See Regex #2 demo. This pattern is basically the same as the first one, just the (?<=\bMove\s+\w+(?:\.\w+)*\s+) lookbehind now also requires a dot-separated word sequence and a whitespace to appear after Move + whitespaces.

I am trying to extend Wiktor's answer to extraxt the source when the source is a string. e.g I want to extract "1" from Move "1" Count. The Regex I have is \b(?<=Move\s+)("[^"]*"|\w+)(?:\.\w+)* which I thought would match a word or a quote, followed by anything which is not a quote and then another quote sign but it does not work. If I create two separate regex expressions they both work but not if I try to combine them into a single expression. Any thoughts on what is going on.

@NigelTunnicliffe @"(?<=\bMove\s+""?)\w+(?:\.\w+)*"? What singular regex? Please update the question with 1) exact source string, 2) expected output.

The expression \b(?<=Move\s+)\w+(?:\.\w+)* matches Move Customer.Name New.Name, and the expression (?<=Move\s+)(""[^""]*"") will match "Nigel" in Move "Nigel" New.Name. What I need to do is combine these into a single statement that will match either Move statement. These expressions are being fed into a third party tool to highlight syntax and this has a limited number of regular expressions it can handle so ideally I need one expression, not two.

Se, https://regex101.com/r/rvPsgo/1?

Thanks Wiktor - I was making things far too complex!
